# R - nonlinear filter to a time series - filter, lapply or loop?

Tags: r, filter, time-series

I have a vector containing simple time series data (extracted from a deSolve matrix), which for testing purposes can be:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

and would like to apply the nonlinear filter

```
x[n]*x[n]-x[n-1]*x[n+1]
```

to all elements of the vector except the first and last elements because the filter can't be applied to these two elements (e.g., when the `x[n-1]` term meets the first element or the `x[n+1]` term meets the last element).  Therein lies my problem.

Things I've tried:
1) The `filter()` command expects a linear filter (i.e., without multiplication of filter coefficients).
2) `lapply()` requires that the function applies to all elements of the list.

Is a loop the only alternative?

Thanks for your help,
Carey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can do it with loop or apply or vectorized.

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> r <- NA
> for (n in 2:length(x)) r[n] <- x[n]*x[n]-x[n-1]*x[n+1]
> (r)
[1] NA  1  1  1 NA
> 
> r <- NA
> lapply(2:length(x),function(n) r[n] <<- x[n]*x[n]-x[n-1]*x[n+1])
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] NA

> (r)
[1] NA  1  1  1 NA

> r <- NA
> r <- x^2 - c(NA,x[1:(length(x)-1)]) * c(x[2:length(x)],NA)
> (r)
[1] NA  1  1  1 NA
```

vectorization is the most efficient but code is harder to decipher

```
> x <- runif(50000)
> 
> r <- NA
> system.time(for (n in 2:length(x)) r[n] <- x[n]*x[n]-x[n-1]*x[n+1])
   user  system elapsed 
   8.55    0.01    8.58 
> 
> r <- NA
> system.time(lapply(2:length(x),function(n) r[n] <<- x[n]*x[n]-x[n-1]*x[n+1]))
   user  system elapsed 
  11.36    0.00   11.39 
> 
> r <- NA
> system.time(r <- x^2 - c(NA,x[1:(length(x)-1)]) * c(x[2:length(x)],NA))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.01
```

Comment: You better initialize R for the complete length : r <- rep(NA,length(x))

Answer (score 3):

1) Try `rollapply` in the zoo package:

```
> library(zoo)
> rollapply(zoo(1:5), 3, function(x) x[2] * x[2] - x[1] * x[3])
2 3 4 
1 1 1
```

`coredata(z)` gives the data portion, i.e. `c(1, 1, 1)`, and `time(z)` gives the time portion, i.e. `c(2, 3, 4)` .

2) Another way to do it in zoo is:

```
> z <- zoo(1:5)
> z*z - lag(z) * lag(z,-1)
2 3 4 
1 1 1
```

3) This last approach also works in ts class found in the core of R:

```
> tt <- ts(1:5)
> tt * tt - lag(tt) * lag(tt, -1)
Time Series:
Start = 2 
End = 4 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 1 1 1
```