# Non-linear filter with recursion in R

Tags: r

I want to apply a non-linear filter to vector in R as follows

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
a<- .5
b<- .5
```

such that

```
>y1 <- x[1]
>y2 <- x[2]+(a*y1)^b
>y3 <- x[3]+(a*y2)^b
>y4 <- x[4]+(a*y3)^b
>y5 <- x[5]+(a*y4)^b
```

which will yield the following vector

```
y<-c(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)
```

how can I achieve this in the most efficient way when the length of x is significantly large

Comment: Are there any approaches or packages you have tried so far?

Comment: I used filter from stats but it allows only linear filtering. I tried vectoring it however I am yet to formulate a generalized vector

Comment: Your question might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135977/r-nonlinear-filter-to-a-time-series-filter-lapply-or-loop, although I'm not sure.  Your filter could be more complex than that solution.  Try it and see!

Comment: I had checked the example before. The problem doesn't seem to have recursion : his required equation being x[n]*x[n]-x[n-1]*x[n+1]. However the the filter I require has recursion as a problem

Answer (score 1):

I think a for-loop is likely to be as efficient as anything else:

```
 y1<- numeric(length(x)); y1[1]=1
 for (n in 2:length(x) ) { y1[n] <- (a*y1[n-1]) ^b + x[n] }
```

When I substituted into your original definition of the filter, and then noted that the exponents were fractional, I decided the simplification was beyond me:

```
> y1 <- x[1]
> y2 <- x[2]+(a*x[1])^b
> y3 <- x[3]+(a*x[2]+(a*x[1])^b)^b
> y4 <- x[4]+(a*x[3]+(a*x[2]+(a*x[1])^b)^b)^b
> y5 <- x[5]+(a*x[4]+(a*x[3]+(a*x[2]+(a*x[1])^b)^b)^b)^b
```